# Can I force AirDrop to work on High Sierra without WiFi hardware?

Tags: software-recommendation, high-sierra, airdrop

Note - my IMac doesn’t have a functioning WiFi card.

The workaround to this before High Sierra was released now doesn’t work for me without a Wi-Fi Card to enable AirDrop.

*additional information: My Wi-Fi Card was removed or disabled due to damage. AirDrop continued to work just fine over ethernet. The lack of a Wi-Fi Card might be what is causing AirDrop not to enable it self in High Sierra.

Is there any third-party app or system modification that performs the same functionality on 10.13?

Comment: So basically this is not a High Sierra specific problem then? Can you edit your question to make this more obvious?

Comment: @patrix yup.. I updated the question.

Comment: Would have been good to know before taking the effort to answer. :/ Hope you find a workable solution.  Cheers!

Comment: I’ve tried to edit this to reduce the chance that more people try to answer assuming WiFi is working. Also - why not add a third party external USB WiFi card so you can just use AirDrop as designed?

Comment: @bmike You think that is possible? Will it work? I have a bunch of USB based WIFI adapters. I can try each one. Let me check.

Answer (score 3):

**Please note that my answer has not been updated after it was made clear that the Wi-Fi hardware had been disabled/removed.**

You can add AirDrop to Finder favourites by going to Preferences->Sidebar and ticking the box next to AirDrop.

If it's missing from there, you can reset the Finder settings by deleting the following files:

~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist

Log out/reboot/force quit Finder to reload the settings.

The [Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106) says AirDrop is supported on 2009 and newer models

Comment: nope not there. I'm on a iMac (27-inch, Late 2013) maybe they dropped support for this model?? dunno.

Comment: Frank has non-functioning hardware - this isn’t an obvious configuration question and more of a hack the system to extend designed functionality type question

Comment: My answer was written before he added the additional information. I will add a note about it.

Comment: Yes - I wonder if there’s another question where your good answer could go live. Thanks for being clear with the edit! I wonder if we could salvage it with a step 1 - use this external USB WiFi adapter that’s known to support AirDrop and turn it on. Then your steps would be a perfect answer for many if not the asker of the question.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: Below was in answer to the original High Sierra question, but it appears that the original question has changed when the hardware issue came to light. I am leaving the answer below posted in case others find it useful when coming across this question.  The hardware should either be fixed or a third party WiFi USB dongle that supports 5GHz 802.11n or 802.11ac can be used to re-enable AirDrop.**

Apple has not removed Airdrop from macOS 10.13 "High Sierra" but if one doesn't see it in the Finder Sidebar, try restoring it.

- Go to Finder > Preferences <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
- Select Sidebar
- Tick the Airdrop checkbox

---

[image: Finder Preferences]

---

[This article from Ars Technica](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/09/macos-10-13-high-sierra-the-ars-technica-review/) review High Sierra and computable Macs.

From the article:

> For a handful of macOS features, mostly related to graphics and wireless communications, you’ll need a system that’s slightly newer
>   than the minimum baseline. For “Continuity” features like AirDrop and
>   Handoff, you’ll need a Mac with both Bluetooth 4.0 and a 5GHz 802.11n
>   or 802.11ac Wi-Fi adapter:
>
> MacBook (Early 2015 and later)
>   **iMac (Late 2012 and later)**
>   MacBook Air (Mid 2012 and later)
>   MacBook Pro (Mid 2012 and later)
>   Mac Mini (Late 2012 and later)
>   Mac Pro (Late 2013)